# Copy class from one element to another

Tags: jquery, clone

Say for example I have a body with the class "test" and I want to take that class and add it to another div, how can I do this with jQuery?

Thanks

Edit: Something like this?

```
 $("body.test").clone().attr("class").prependTo("div");
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy the style for that class to another div?

Comment: No I want to add a class to my body and have it append itself to a specific element.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
$('element').hasClass("test", function() {
 $('element2').addClass("test");
} );
```

should do it - syntactically untested, but it's roughly what I'd do.

Comment: Syntactically should be something like:

if ( $('element').hasClass("test") )
{
   $('element2').addClass('test');
}

seems to be the method structure - can never remember syntax!

Answer (score 49):

I stumbled upon your question while searching for a solution to the same problem. Though the proposed solution works, you've got to know the class name.

here is another way to do it without knowing the classes names. As you thought, it uses `.attr()`

```
 $("#MyTargetElementId").attr("class", $("body.ToCopy").attr("class"));
```

Using multiple selectors is not really working though, which kind of makes sense :)

Answer (score 8):

You should use this if you just want to add classes from another element without removing the existing classes:

```
$('.i_want_your_classes').addClass( $('.have_my_classes').attr("class") );
```

Answer (score 0):

The link below might help you to copy class or id attributes from an element to another. It also contains live examples how to do it.

http://html-tuts.com/copy-class-id-to-another-html-element-with-jquery/

---

**Here are some short examples:**

Copy all classes from an element to another

```
$('.differentClass').addClass( $('.anotherClass').attr('class') );
```

If element has multiple classes, get them in array and copy only the second class (or any other class):

```
var getClasses = $('.someClass').attr('class');
var splitClasses = getClasses.split(' ');

$('.differentClass').addClass( splitClasses[1] );
```

*This will result in the array below, and you can output values by providing the array position:*

```
splitClasses[0] => 'firstClass'
splitClasses[1] => 'secondClass'
splitClasses[2] => 'thirdClass'
```

Copy Id from Elemenet to Another

```
$('.someClass').attr( 'id', $('#someId').attr('id') );
```